# Conveying the idea of "It's piece of cake" by "simple comme bonjour" or "bête comme chou"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

L'autre jour j'ai voulu dire

> "I cannot understand the grades. The exam paper was a piece of cake."

J'ai dit :

> Les notes sont inexplicables. Les sujets étaient simples comme bonjour."

Je ne suis pas sûr si j'ai été bien compris et si j'ai bien rendu l'élémentarité des sujets.

En révanche, je trouve l'expression

> ...Les sujets étaient bêtes comme choux.

familière.

"Simple comme bonjour" convient-elle dans ce contexte ? Peut-on utiliser "Bête comme choux" à la place ?

Comment: Heuuu... Dimitris... Je dis ça je dis rien maintenant... si tu dis ça à des étudiants qui viennent de se vautrer... ça casse un peu! Tu trouves pas ? ;-) Enfin... je veux dire... suffisamment pour qu'ils n'aient pas envie de comprendre quoi que ce soit... Je veux dire... les raisons de l'incompréhension des autres peuvent ne pas être de l'ordre du langage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Simple comme bonjour*** convient. Est-ce que c'est ce que dirait la majorité des enseignants dans ce cas, je ne sais pas.

Spontanément j'aurais dit :

- ***Je n'aurais pas pu faire plus simple***.

Formulation ambiguë qui permet d'introduire l'éventualité que j'aurais pu mal avoir évalué la difficulté du sujet<sup>1</sup>.

- ***C'était pourtant facile***.

Éviterait de mettre la responsabilisé de l'enseignant en jeu.

***Bête comme chou***  est moins courant de nos jours et je le déconseillerais pour la raison qu'un enseignant, à quelque niveau que ce soit, ne peut pas sous-entendre que ses étudiants ne sont pas capables de faire quelque chose de bête (et donc qu'ils sont bêtes eux-mêmes), tu le dis toi-même c'est inapproprié, tout comme le serait d'autres formulations impliquant un trop grand jugement de valeur négatif (utilisation d'un superlatif genre « simplissime » ou qualificatif genre « dérisoire »).

***C'est du gâteau***  est une expression très proche de l'anglais *easy as pie*/*it's a piece of cake* et qui existe depuis longtemps en français, je suis sûre que c'est compris de tout le monde mais je ne sais pas si c'est encore très employé chez les jeunes<sup>2</sup>.

***C'est un jeu d'enfant*** est une autre expression très courante et comprise de tous souvent utilisée pour rendre aussi bien *it's a piece of cake* que *it's child's play*.

---

Hors question mais à signaler quand même : l'emploi du passif dans ta phrase (« Les notes sont inexplicables » n'est pas ce qu'on dirait spontanément, en français la forme active est plus courante : « je ne m'explique pas les notes ».

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> L'enseignant devant toujours respecter les étudiants (même si le contraire n'est pas toujours le cas, je le sais).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Je suis sûre que de plus jeunes participants de FL pourront éclairer  ce point.</sub>

Comment: En plus du gâteau il y aussi "c'est de la tarte".

Comment: @MathieuBouville Est-ce que ça s'emploie à la forme affirmative ? Personnellement je ne l'emploie qu'à la forme négative, « c'est pas de la tarte » pour dire que c'est difficile.

Answer (score 2):

Je suis bien d'accord avec vous : il y a certainement un élément de familiarité dans ces deux expressions ;  la seconde parait même plus familière que la première ;  à  en croire le TLFi, ce serait vrai : probablement par erreur, le TLFi liste cette première expression deux fois, une première fois sous l'entrèe « bonjour », une deuxième sous « simple », et sous cette dernière la stipulation « fam. » n'est pas portée.

> ([TLFi, A. 2.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bonjour)) Expr. (fam.) Sans article. Simple comme bonjour
>
> ([TLFi, I.B. 3. b)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/simple) Simple comme bonjour. Qui coule de source, qui est évident.
>
> - J'ai une brave femme de mère qui habite la campagne (...) C'est simple comme bonjour, votre gamin lui tiendra compagnie. (GONCOURT, Sœur Philom., 1861, p. 165)
>
> ([TLFi, D. *Expr. fam.*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chou))  C'est bête comme chou. C'est facile à comprendre ou à faire. C'est bête comme chou, c'est simple, vous pouvez en faire autant... Essayez (CENDRARS, Bourlinguer, 1948, p. 182).

L'[internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/20198/simple-comme-bonjour/) et le
[wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/simple_comme_bonjour) confirment que la première n'est pas familière et de plus que la seconde est un synonyme à part entière.

Une autre source, [expressions françaises synonymes](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-s/2537-simple-comme-bonjour.html), fournit les informations suivantes.

> Exemple d’utilisation : Les gars se mettent au boulot et qu’est ce que Gonzalès dégotte ? une correspondance du senor Vindez avec le parti populaire français, d’où il ressortait qu’il donnait des renseignements au P.P.F. sur les organisations de gauche. Ca suffit dit Gonzalès en montrant ses papiers au vieux, suivez moi, votre compte est bon, c’est simple comme bonjour, il suffisait d’y penser. (A. Sergent)
>
> Expressions françaises synonymes : Bête comme chou, les doigts dans le nez, con comme la lune, c’est du gâteau

On voit que dans l'exemple ci-dessus cette expression est associé à un vocabulaire informel ou marqué : « gars » (fam. TLFi), « dégotter » (pop. et fam., TLFi), « vieux » (un terme qui selon le TLFi est employé  « souvent avec une valeur de mépris ou de condescendance »). De plus les synonymes sont  très familiers et même populaires.

1/ (TLFi) C'est du gâteau, pop.

2/ (TLFi) Loc. Con comme la lune. Tout à fait idiot.

- Je le trouvais con comme la lune. (CÉLINE, Mort à crédit, 1936, p. 155)

La seconde expression est encore considérée comme du langage normal par le TLFi mais il y a encore des français à ne pas accepter cela ; d'ailleurs, d'après l'œuvre dans laquelle est pris l'exemple, un livre dans la langue de Céline, lequel se donne librement à l'usage d'un abondant vocabulaire argotique que la licence poétique, à mon avis, n'excuse pas, son emploi n'est pas marqué par le cachet de la plus élégante expression.

En conclusion de ce que l'on peut glaner dans les dictionnaires, les deux expressions sont utilisables, mais de la part d'un professeur s'adressant à ses élèves et voulant garder son langage sobre,  libre d'effets ostentatoires, pour ne pas dire ronflants,  ce ne sont pas les termes de la langue la plus pure. Je ne les emploierais pas. À mon avis la première, malgré l'avis du TLFi, est quand même préférable à la seconde (si l'on n'insiste pas sur un style bien châtié).

Des expressions courantes pas spécialement formelles

- de la plus grande simplicité
- sans la moindre difficulté
- d'une difficulté dérisoire

Comment: On peut dire d'une personne qu'elle est « con comme la lune », on ne le dit en principe d'une chose. De toute façon ça serait inapproprié dans le contexte donné dans la question.

Comment: @Laure > J'ai déjà entendu sans être choqué, peut-être ou sans doute par abus de language, dire d'une chose qu'elle est "con comme la lune".